# Change docker-compose propagation settings

Tags: docker

I trying to change the propagation settings of docker compose. Below is my yaml file.

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /app
        bind:
          propagation: shared
```

However when I docker-inspect the container the volume is still rprivate.

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/c/users/pinku/Desktop/workflow/frontend",
                "Destination": "/app",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "9a085880e8938e31a5b8d4a66b53700b26d3b279799d614a26e82134dd0f58d5",
                "Source": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/9a085880e8938e31a5b8d4a66b53700b26d3b279799d614a26e82134dd0f58d5/_data",
                "Destination": "/app/node_modules",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ]
```

Any idea about what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is the `docker-compose` version that you use ?

Comment: It's at the top of the file. 3.2

Comment: I mean the result of `docker-compose --version` which gives the docker-compose version

Comment: @MostafaHussein sorry I got confused, it is 1.20.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a bunch of related GitHub issues: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5212 and https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34936

Try to update your docker-compose installation (1.21+) and change the value of version directive to at least version "3.3".